# scrollable select consistent across browsers?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, cross-browser

I need to create a dropdown, which can contain 100s of options.

I need a scrollbar to appear and be consistent across all browsers.

Google came up empty: Is there a good URL that describes if this is consistent or not?

Comment: wouldn't the standard select tag be enough in your case?

Comment: I am not 100% certain, but I think some browsers behave differently with a larger-than-screen-size select widget.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would strongly recommend against having a scrollable select with 100s of options for usability reasons.

With exception of one corner case, navigating (both searching in, and selecting from) that list is a really really hard and very annoying to the user.

The UI design reasoning is that it requires:

- Wide mouse gesture (tiring), followed by immediate precise stop (hard to do because of inertia)
- Very difficult to use interface of a scrollbar (extra crap points for scrollbar being in the middle of the page instead of on the right side) - see Jacob Nielsen's and others' usual ranting about difficulties of using scrollbars and general evil of anything too long that requires much scrolling.
- Eyes need to scan whole page worth of menu up and down and back, all the time. very tiring.

[Here is a set of bad examples](http://www.gui-bloopers.com/more.php)

[ the corner case is when all the option names are uniformly distributed across the alphabet (as far as the first letter), which allows somewhat-possible keyboard-only navigation in the drop-down via pressing the first letter of an option ].

A proper UI solution is to have a select whose contents are dynamically populated based on a search field - either typed text (think Google's new search box, or browser's address bar) or sometimes checkboxes/radio buttons.

BTW, sub-menu solutions also suck for mouse navigation - minor twitch of the wrist and you lost all of the pointing work.

I apologize that this answer is not an answer to "how do you solve my technical problem", but I am of a very strong opinin that you're solving the wrong problem in the first place.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for this DVK. In fact, I am trying to convince my client of the same opinion, and was tyring to find ammunition as to why using a scrollable select may eventually become unwieldy (as more options are added).

Comment: I edited and added a link that has some illustrations of why it's a bad idea. 
P.S. As a shameless self-promotion, I would as that you mark this answer as an accepted answer, if that link comes in useful talking to your client.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **no**, for the standard HTML `select` element and the requirements you describe.

However, do you know you can set the `size` attribute for how many rows are visible at one time? AFAIK this will force scrolling in all browsers, but it isn't a drop down. Like this:

```
<select size="10">
  <option>etc</option>
  ...
</select>
```

There is also the possiblity of `optgroup` to split the options into categories.

If you have many categories you could do what I did on one site and use this [jQuery click menu](http://p.sohei.org/jquery-plugins/clickmenu/), using the click function to set a hidden field. So now I have a dropdown with sub-categories and it's quite easy to find the right option.